# How to use clickLongOnScreen(x, y) in Robotium?

Tags: android, robotium

I am new to *Robotium* .For the method `clickLongOnScreen(x, y)`, I know x and y are the coordinates. But how can I get coordinates value ? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to your device (or emulator) Settings screen -> Developer options -> Show Pointer location.
2. Check it's checkbox.
3. look on the top of the screen and there you'll see the X and Y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

If u have the view id, you con use the following to write test case that work on all screen sizes.

```
int[] location = new int[2];
View view = solo.getView(id);
view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int x= location[0];
int y= location[1];
```